# How to save row changes in DevExpress GridView with the EmbeddedNavigator

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I am using the EmbeddedNavigator's Add, Edit and Remove buttons. I have subscribed to the `gridControl1_EmbeddedNavigator_ButtonClick` event and there I check which button is clicked.

The problem is that when I edit a cell and I press save changes(`EndEdit`) I don't see the new values.
Here is the code that I have:

```
private void gridControl1_EmbeddedNavigator_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.NavigatorButtonClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button.ButtonType == DevExpress.XtraEditors.NavigatorButtonType.EndEdit)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the changes?", "Save changes?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    var rowHandle = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;

                    // Here if the port is null by default, when I change it to 25
                    // I still get an empty string
                    var port = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "ftpPort"));

                    var ftpConfig = new FtpConfiguration() { ftpPort = port };
                    // Update and save
                    context.UpdateFtpConfiguration(ftpConfig);
                    context.Save();
                }
                else
                    e.Handled = true;
            }
}
```

Maybe I have to append them to the row first, but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to post your changes to underlying `DataSource` before saving it:

```
if (gridView1.IsEditing)
    gridView1.CloseEditor();

if (gridView1.FocusedRowModified)
    gridView1.UpdateCurrentRow();
```

Comment: Thanks! Closing the editor did the trick. Now the changes are included and I can easily update the row in the database.

Comment: Thanks, i was missing the updateCurrentRow method call. =D