# XtraGrd.GetRow(XtraGrd.FocusedRowHandle) doesn't get the value of the focused TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

In my `WinForm` application when I want to add a row in `xtragrid`, I have a problem with getting the current value of the **focused** `textbox`.

Assume I have a `textBox` bind to `Model.VchType.Title` , Before I click Save button my **focus** is on `txtTitle` and I typed "title1" on it.

This is my code for Save button event:

```
Model.VchType row = xtraGrd.GetRow(xtraGrd.FocusedRowHandle) as Model.VchType;
```

I get `null` for `row.Title` after it hits the break point in this line of code.
And this problem only occurs when right before I click on save button **focus** is on `txtTitle`.

-------- UPDATE ------------

Here is some of code of model:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("vwVchType", Schema = "Sle")]
[Serializable]
public class VchType : Entity
{
    private int _ID;
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column]
    [RnDisplayName(typeof(Rnw.Sle.Properties.Resources), "ID")]
    public override int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _ID;
        }
        set
        {
            _ID = value;
        }
    }

    private string _Title;
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column]
    [RnDisplayName(typeof(Rnw.Sle.Properties.Resources), "Title")]        
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return _Title;
        }
        set
        {
            _Title = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Also I created columns by **designer**.

I fill a `bindingSource` and set the property of the `datasource` of grid to this bindingsource in designer.

And I don't think problem is column name , because if before I click save button I focus on another controller, It works fine and I get value for `row.Title`.

Comment: Is the Textbox a repositoryitem in the grid? Or is the Textbox out of the GridComponent?

Comment: @Sebi Its a repositoryitem in the grid

Comment: Please try to set the focus on any other object before you save your data. It's not that clean but i have some projects where this was helpful. So the first action in your save method is to set the focus to any label or sth. out of the grid.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26712617/1805640)?

Comment: @Sebi I tried to set focus on another label , but didn't worked

Comment: @nempoBu4 That didn't work in my case

Comment: @Sebi , In second try your idea worked, Thanks. If u post it as an answer I will mark it.

Comment: @HosseinPanahloo your welcome. I answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can focus another forms object before you save your data. So call:

```
anyControl.Select();
```

Before you save. This will close the open editor from your Textbox and post the changes to your DataSource. Normally this should be done by `PostEditor();` which sometimes seems to lack.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
((GridView)xtraGrid.FocusedView).PostEditor();
```

or
`gridView.PostEditor()`this will save the current value to the editor `EditValue`.
Then you need to call `view.UpdateCurrentRow()` to validate the focused row and save its values to the data source.

So you need something like this

```
((GridView)xtraGrid.FocusedView).PostEditor();
((GridView)xtraGrid.FocusedView).UpdateCurrentRow();
Model.VchType row = xtraGrd.GetRow(xtraGrd.FocusedRowHandle) as Model.VchType;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I used gridView.PostEditor() , but problem didn't solve. Still get null for row.Title

Comment: gridView.FocusedView.PostEditor(); , it says gridView dosn't contain definition for FocusedView. So I used gridView.PostEditor() instead. But didnt solve the peoblem.

Comment: Can you post more of your code. Especially the model.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code that is for the model and also how do you set it to the grid's DataSource. Also if you've created the columns "by hand" or by using the designer, make sure that the column's FieldName is "Title" the FieldName of the column must match the property name of the model class. You can use nameof operator if your are using C# >= 5 colTitle.FieldName = nameof(VchType.Title)

Comment: Also FocusedView is a property of the grid itself not the view, that's why you get the compile error.

Comment: Can you post the code from the .designer.cs file that is setting the Title columns properties

Comment: this.colTitle.FieldName = "Title";
            this.colTitle.Name = "colTitle";
            this.colTitle.Visible = true;
            this.colTitle.VisibleIndex = 7;

Comment: Everything seems OK to me. I won't be able to help you if you do not post all the code.

Comment: Just try this one and let me know if it will work. After calling PostEditor() call view.UpdateCurrentRow(); See my updated answer.